# Adding Highchartsevent after creation

Tags: angular, events, highcharts

I wan't to add and remove events after the creation of the chart. The problem is that I can't get the properties of the chart by handling the event. Like:

```
event.xAxis[0].min
```

I created a example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sw9fbo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Line 55:

```
private addEvents(): void {    
      Highcharts.addEvent(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, 'selection', (event) => {
      // problem can't get xAxis or any properties of the chart
      console.log('selection->x-min: ', event.xAxis[0].min); 
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd4svb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two little flaws, that break the behavior:

First, you need to actually call your `addEvents` method. instead of `this.addEvents;` in line 43, you need to call `this.addEvents();`

Second, the `Highcharts.addEvent()`-method expects you to pass the actual chart object - not the reference to its container. So change line 50 to

```
Highcharts.addEvent(this.chart, 'selection', (event) => {
```

to pass the chart created above.

### Edit:

To remove your TypeScript compile errors and get full autocomplete functionality, you need to manually install the appropriate type-package from npm.

```
npm install --save @types/highcharts
```

import the specific Event Type accordingly`at the top of your File.

```
import {ChartSelectionEvent} from 'highcharts';
```

and finally add the Type accordingly to the function signature.

```
Highcharts.addEvent(this.chart, 'selection', (event: ChartSelectionEvent ) => {
```

I [updated your stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1iefq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve the problem with the properties.

Comment: Are you talking about the TypeScript recognition of members? Cause the compiled JS is actually able to read the fields...

Comment: maybe. I got a compile error: "Property 'xAxis' does not exist on type 'Event'". If i zoom it have to print the min and max values of xAxis into the console.

Comment: You're right. It's about the TypeScript recognition of members.  I got a compile error: "Property 'xAxis' does not exist on type 'Event'". And it would be great if this error disappear and that I can use autocompletion.

Comment: Adding `: any` to your parameter in line 53 will remove the compile error: `Highcharts.addEvent(this.chart, 'selection', (event: any) => {`
But this will not add autocomplete functionality...

Comment: @KarLito: I updated my answer, now also considering type mismatching.